# md-checkbox proper verification

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

If I set an input to required on angular material and submit the form the error message / red styling appears. For md-checkbox however, there is nothing if I set it to required. How to make a proper validation for required checkboxes? Is there really no default verfication?

Answer (score 0):

Put a default value to false to your binded data

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have this checkbox with data.formModel.acceptPrivacyPolicy set to false in the controller. What am I missing?
<md-checkbox ng-model="data.formModel.acceptPrivacyPolicy" aria-label="{{'Privacy Policy'|translate}}" required>
        <span ng-bind-html="data.links.privacy"></span>
       </md-checkbox>

Comment: Can you provide a plunker to illustrate it please ?

Comment: I just modified an existing one; hope I didn't leave anything out, but that's how it looks for my real app as well: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyVawV

Comment: hum... Try to update your version of angular material and angular if possible. You work on old version
I saw issue with md-checkbox in older version

Comment: Sorry i re-read your post and i think i make a mistake. How do you defined a checkbox as required ?

Comment: Sorry i re-read your post and i think i make a mistake. How do you defined a checkbox as required ?
Required property can't be set. You can reject form if chekbox isn't dirty. But if checkbox value is undefined or false, it's not consider as a required error.

Comment: So could you please give an example for a terms&conditions md-checkbox where the error messages get displayed when submitting? (together with all other required messages of other inputs)

Comment: By default there is no error displayed for checkbox. Angular material is based on angular. So you can check angular documentation for input (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) to see possible errors on input at form submitting.
If default behaviors doesn't corresponds to your needs you can provide custom validators (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)